# Получаю 8 елементов в массиве вместо 3

Tags: javascript

```js
let set = [];

let john = {
  name: "John"
};
let pete = {
  name: "Pete"
};
let mary = {
  name: "Mary"
};

set.push(john);
set.push(pete);
set.push(mary);
set.push(john);
set.push(mary);


arr = new Map();
for (let key of set) {
  if (!arr.has(key)) {
    arr.set(key, 1);
    set.push(key);
  }
}

console.log(set);
```

По идее тут должны оставаться уникальные значения в map которые  я добавляю в массив, в map добавляется 3 ключа но в массив уже почему-то добавляется 8 объектов

////Как я решил проблему(оказалось я затупил и запутался что и куда я добавляю)

```
arr = new Map();
for (let key = 0; key < set.length; key++) {
  if (!arr.has(set[key])) {
    arr.set(set[key], 1);
  } else {
    set.splice(key, 1);
    key--;
  }
}
```

Comment: А про 5 строк `set.push`, написанных перед Map, вы уже забыли?)

Answer (score 0):

> Я не эксперт в JavaScript, но по моему, уникальный ключ может быть
> только в объекте. А вот в массив, по идее, может состоять из -
>
> ```
> [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
> ```

Все, что написано выше - не точно, будьте любезны, можете меня поправить и я изменю ответ

Можете написать ф-ию, которая оставит только уникальные значение.

**ВНИМАНИЕ!**, функция подойдет только для не больших массивов.

```
function unique(arr) {
  let result = [];

  for (let str of arr) {
    if (!result.includes(str)) {
      result.push(str);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

let strings = ["кришна", "кришна", "харе", "харе",
  "харе", "харе", "кришна", "кришна", ":-O"
];

alert( unique(strings) )
```

Comment: Люблю больше англоязычное сообщество этого сайта, там не поставят молча минус

Comment: ага ага, там просто удалят такой вопрос раньше, чем кто-то напишет ответ

Comment: Та ладно с вопросом, я какое плохое зло сделал?(

Comment: Спасибо, добрые люди

Comment: Меня интересовала ошибка в коде, человек в коментарии мне подсказал, решение я уже сам для себя придумал, если интересно то прикреплено к вопросу